# jquery: set the value of the added input with the append one at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

With ajax, I add to a table one row of an item and therefore imposed the id value of an input (connected to a button that opens the php page with that specific item card).
The first entry (via append) is ok: the item is properly displayed and its id is properly assigned to the button
but when I add (via append) the following item in the subsequent lines, the id of the setting of these successive item does not work: each of these id has the value of all ( `id_item = 1 & id_item = 2 & id_item = 3 ...` ).
The append function does not retain the attributes settings?
Enclosed is the code that I use:

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function(id_item) {
    var row_appended = (
        '<tr class="class_tr" id="id_tr">' +
            '<td width="90%">NEW ITEM</td>' +

            '<td width="10%">' +
                '<form method="GET" action="see_item.php">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="id_item" class="id_item" value=0>' +
                '<button type="submit" class="button_change_item" title="see item">See item</button>'+
                '</form>' +
            '</td>' +

        '</tr>'
        );

    //$(append).appendTo('table#tabella_elenco_clienti');
    //OR:
    $("#table_items").last().append(row_appended);

    //$('table#table_items tr :input[value="0"]').val(id_item);
    //OR:
    $('#table_items tr:last :input.id_item').val(id_item);
},
  error: function(){
    alert("Error!!!");
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual HTML, but It looks like both of the jQuery lines are wrong. The first looks like it's adding the new row inside of the last row of the table instead of after the last row. The second jquery line doesn't appear to be valid and should be necessary. To fix the second one, you should be able to change the generated HTML: `'<input type="hidden" name="id_item" class="id_item" value="' + id_item + '">' +`

Comment: Basic example of what you're trying to do: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxhwo6kh/)

Comment: @Anialation, thanks, but in your script all items have the same id. If the item n. 2 has a different id (collect by php page via ajax), the script set the same id :-(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your commend. The script I provided has a different value on each of the hidden inputs named "id_item".  Did you want them to be the same? When I inspect the elements in the browser the ID's are unique.

Comment: #Anialation, sorry for my bad English. With your (and my) script, each id_item in the rows appended are the same. Maybe, because "Those append id's don't exists for .click because they are not on the dom" (cit. Caius, in his answer below). If I set the value attribute with ".val(id-Item)", the second (and the first) value became "id_item=1&id_item=2"...

Comment: They are note the same in my code. I am injecting the id_item into the HTML for each line with this: `'<input type="hidden" name="id_item" class="id_item" value="' + id_item + '">' +`. The ` + id_item + ` is doing that. So the ID's are different for each row. There's no need for a jQuery call later to set the ID.

Comment: You're rigth, thank you so much. Thanks to all, guys, you are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem it's not on the append function it's on the jquery or jscript execution.
Those append id's don't exists for .click because they are not on the dom
so you should use a jquery `.live`|`.on` jquery action instead of `.click`

[juqery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I just se you are creating a submit button on every execution but not a form, just keep in mind you will submit all the hidden inputs in one beacause it has the same name